# Can an n-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ have lebesgue measure 0?

Tags: manifolds, lebesgue-measure

It follows from Sard's theorem that if a submanifold $\mathcal{M}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies $\dim \mathcal{M}<n$, then $\mathcal{M}$ has measure zero.

What about the converse situation? If a submanifold $\mathcal{P}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has measure zero, does this imply that $\dim \mathcal{P} < n$?

Comment: Can't we just note that each point has a coordinate chart, which is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and therefore has positive measure?

Comment: This corollary of Sard's theorem is only for smooth submanifolds. There are topological submanifolds of $R^n$ of dimension $<n$ and positive $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @NateEldredge I think your answer is solid. If you want to submit it as an answer I will mark it correct!